# Adding update site URLs to find third-party dependencies during install

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2

I have an Eclipse feature which when installing on Helios requires an additional update-site URL to be present in order to find certain dependencies. Is it possible to automatically add such an URL so that the user doesn't have to do it manually? Or is it considered bad practice to do so?

I've tried to add `addRepository` action to the p2.inf file of the feature, but it is not executed.

Comment: Could you add more detail about why below answer doesn't work?

Answer (score 7):

The only way I have found is to add repository references into `content.jar/content.xml` by hand. For example, to add EMF update site into the list of available update sites one can add the following code to `<repository>` node:

```
<references size="2">
    <repository uri="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/updates/" url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/updates/" type="0" options="0"/>
    <repository uri="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/updates/" url="http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/updates/" type="1" options="0"/>
</references>
```

I did't found any documentation describing what `type` and `options` attributes mean. Also this solution will not work if the specified update site has already been added to available sites as disabled site (check Window -> Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Software). In such case it is not enabled, actually I was searching how to enable it unconditionally, and found your question.

There is also [an Ant script](http://divby0.blogspot.com/2011/02/simplifying-p2-process-part-3-associate.html) which simplifies adding associated sites into `content.jar/content.xml`.

Please let me know if you'll find a better way.

### UPD.

It is possible to associate a new update site with a slightly different URL, for example

```
http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/updates/
```

->

```
http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/updates/#contributed-by-my-update-site
```

But I still hope that there is a better solution.

Comment: I suspect that the `type` attribute is whether the repository is an artifact or metadata repo. This is one of the parameters to the addRepository() p2 action.

Comment: What about the `<url/>` tag in `feature.xml`? It doesn't seem to work for me, however.

Answer (score 2):

As Raffi comments on Eldars answer an external update site for dependencies can be added by putting the following entry in the `feature.xml` file.

```
<url>
  <discovery label="Example Update Site" url="http://example.se/update_site/"/>
</url>
```

This can also be done through the `feature.xml` editor GUI, in the *Information* → *Sites to Visit* tab.

In the GUI this is described as "*update sites to visit while looking for new features*".

This seem to generate the entries in `content.jar/content.xml` that Eldar describes in their answer.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work. The site is added in feature.xml, but Eclipse doesn't download any dependency.