# Eclipse plugin dev, cannot find dependency org.eclipse.jsch.core

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have decided to enhance an existing eclipse plugin called [JCTerm](http://www.jcraft.com/eclipse-jcterm/). I am trying to install my enhanced version on another instance of eclipse (I am able to successfully run it in my local eclipse as I seem to have all the dependencies). Obviously depdenencies such as `org.eclipse.core.runtime` are found, however dependencies such as `com.jcraft.jsch` I am not so sure about. And `org.eclipse.jsch.core` is definetly giving me errors when I try to install this on another instance of eclipse.

I have these plugins defined, I created a new features project and also clicked 'Compute Depenencies`. I then created a third project to create the update site. When I try installing from the update site, it complains about missing dependencies.

In short, I have no idea how to deal with these dependencies issues in Eclipse Plugin Development and Google has been entirely useless regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to install your feature, the Eclipse instance must know the update sites of all dependencies of your plugins. On your system, you manually installed the JCraft stuff (or at least added its update site) when you installed JTerm for the first time. On the second system, you need to add the JCraft update site manually and to check the checkbox "Search all update sites..." in the bottom left corner of the installation dialog before trying to install your plugin.

As an alternative, you can modify your update site files and try to [hack the third party dependencies into your update site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254116/adding-update-site-urls-to-find-third-party-dependencies-during-install), then the installation should run fine without manual steps in between.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Eclipse are you developing on?  The [JCraft site](http://www.jcraft.com/eclipse-cvsssh2/) describes plugins that run on Eclipse versions up to and including 3.x.  I'd look to this site to see what the correct versions of jcraft plugins are appropriate to the version of Eclipse you're using.

Comment: My local eclipse where I have this running (clicking the run icon) is 3.7 / indigo. This is also the same version on another machine where it fails to install.

Comment: Did you install the jcraft plugins in the new Eclipse?

Comment: I don't believe that page pertain to me? I am looking to install JCTerm, The link you have is for CVS-SSH.

Comment: Yes I installed JCTerm on the machine where I am trying to install my enhanced plugin. Yet I still do not seem to have the dependency available... Strange.

Comment: Confirm that each of the dependencies has been installed by looking at the plugin registry (Window -> Show View).  Also look at the error log view to see if any of the dependencies are throwing errors on startup.