# Can plugins made with Xtext 2.3 be deployed on Eclipse 3.7 or earlier?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext

Xtext 2.0 was released with Eclipse Indigo (3.7).
Xtext 2.3 was released with Eclipse Juno (3.8/4.2).

I have developed a plugin with Xtext 2.3. I tried to install it on 3.7 but it installs Xtext 2.0.1 as a dependency, and then the editor does not seem to work. If I use Xtext 2.3 does it mean my clients have to use Juno or later, or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xtext 2.3 can be installed over Indigo as well using the update site http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/ Simply add it in the Add new software dialog, and then you can install it.

On the other hand, if you want your code to work with Xtext 2.0, then you have to modify (and test) your code with Xtext 2.0 as well, at the minimum you have to update the dependencies in manifest.mf files, and also might need to regenerate the editor with Xtext 2.0, and possibly modify some of your manually written code.

Comment: Thanks! I want to deploy it to clients, so I guess [questions like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254116/adding-update-site-urls-to-find-third-party-dependencies-during-install) are relevant as to how to get clients to install it as well.